# What is the "ghconduit.com" certificate in my Keychain for?

Tags: macos, github, keychain

I have a certificate in my Keychain called "ghconduit.com" and I have no clue what it is used for.

According to the WHOIS of the domain it belongs to GitHub but I can't find any information about its purpose.

Comment: I've received a tweet from a GitHub employee saying it is for allowing GitHub apps to talk to one another https://twitter.com/holman/status/410083585333268480

Comment: @AndyLester That's not the Conduit referred to here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is related to the ["Open file"](https://github.com/blog/1650-opening-files-from-pull-requests-and-branches) support in [GitHub for Mac](http://mac.github.com/).

However, the fact that anything was added to the keychain is a bug that's since been fixed. You can safely delete the certificate from your keychain and it won't be re-added.